# Add custom CSS class via variable to returned jsx

Tags: reactjs, typescript, ionic-react

I've created a custom component which essentially returns html markup in order to display content based on the values passed to the component. Here's a simplified version for brevity:

```
interface ContainerProps {
    position?: string;
    content?: string;
    class?: string;
}

const CardContainer: React.FC<ContainerProps> = ({ position = "right", content = "n/a", class = "" }) => {
    
    if ( position.trim().toLowerCase() === "right" ) {
        return <><div className="ion-float-right" >{content}</div><div className="clear-right"></div></>
    } else if ( position.trim().toLowerCase() === "left" ) {
        return <div className="ion-float-left">{content}</div> 
    } else {
        return null
    }
    
};

export default CardContainer;
```

This works great, but I now need to be able to pass a css class name to the component. However, I can't work out how to add the "class" prop to the returned html/jsx.

I tried various code such as below. However, in all cases the code was output as actual html rather than the value of the prop:

```
return <div className="ion-float-left" + {class}>{content}</div> 

return <div className="ion-float-left {class}" >{content}</div> 

return <div className="ion-float-left class">{content}</div>
```

I also tried a few other random things in desperation and these typically cause a compilation error. What is the best way to achieve the intended result eg:

```
return <div className="ion-float-left myClassNameHere">{content}</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

its like inserting a string inside another or adding them together. You can use classname={"yourclasse" + theDynamicClass} or className={`yourClass ${dynamicClass}`} (inbetween ``)

Answer (score 1):

return <div className=` ion-float-left ${class}``>{content}

Comment: Thanks for the response. It's recommended that SO answers should explain the the solution rather than just posting code snippets.

Comment: Okay, thanks for the info, this is my first answer so I didn't know

Comment: No problem, I could see that you were new. Giving an explanation helps people learn but also makes it harder for someone to give out dangerous code.